# Swap some words in the content of the selected tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say I want to change the content of the selected tab in chrome extension. I want to replace every occurrence of `come` with a `fly`.

How can I dynamically change the words?

So far, I reach the `document` and `replace` all occurrence of the word `come` but couldn't write the updated content into the selected tab.

What I wrote is;

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    updatedContent = document.replace(/come, 'fly');

});
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit: My mistake, document.replace does not function well.

Edit2: With the suggestion of @Haibara Ai I edited as;

```
chrome.tabs.query( {active: true, currentWindow: true} ,function (tabs) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { code: 'document.body.outerHTML.replace(/come/g, "fly")' });
});
```

But nothing happened. There is also no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` is called in the context of the extension, while the dom you want to access lives in the process of the web page, you can not directly manipulate it from background page.

To achieve what you want, you could take a look at [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), which allows you to do programming injection, sample code looks like:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},
    (tabs) => chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: 'document.replace(/come, "fly");'}));
```

Please be aware `document.replace` doesn't work well, you could use other methods like `document.body.innerHTML.replace` instead.

BTW, `chrome.tabs.getSelected` has been deprecated, use `chrome.tabs.query{active: true}` instead.

Comment: thank you very much, but when I try your code inside `window.onload = function(){}` it did not work. And gave me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at line `(tabs) => chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: 'document.replace(/come, 'fly');'});`

Comment: @user6468132, that's just a sample code, you would need to use your own `replace` method, and don't forget to deal with quote and permissions issue.

Comment: When I run the same in the console which is  `document.body.outerHTML.replace(/come/g, "fly")`  , the outerHTML is changed but nothing changed in the page.should be added to make these changes appear in the page?

Comment: @user6468132, you should use `document.write` to replace with the new string. And don't forget to add `activeTab` permissions in your `manifest.json`

Comment: I solve the situation, `document.body.outerHTML = document.body.outerHTML.replace(/come/g, "fly")` makes the change :)